# Создание обобщенного шаблона

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте уважаемые знатоки Django!
Сам я не первый год знаком с python и с недавнего времени начал все стороннее осваивание django и у меня возник вопрос:
возможно ли разбить общий шаблон так, чтобы не генерировать в view функции огромный словарь для шаблона всей страницы, а из самого шаблона вызывать нужный обработчик и получать на его место обработанный кусок общей весрстки? На php это типа `include("file.php");`. То что описывается в книгах (наследование и подключение шаблонов) дает только сам шаблон с тегами, а хочется как-то получить полностью обработанный кусок...

P.S: Заранее извиняюсь за кривоватое изложение мысли. За 15 часов битрикса мозг раскисает(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению то, что вы хотите сделать (вызвать управляющую логику из другого файла прямо в шаблоне) - сделать нельзя. Это просто противоречило бы MVC (MTV в нашем случаи) т.к. templates был бы наделен функциями view и весь паттерн был бы нарушен.
Так что вам все равно придется передавать большие словари и конечно же templates вам позволяют с разных сторон ими манипулировать перед тем, как вывести на экран.

Comment: как раз то что я и хотел услышать спасибо)

Comment: Это не правда, как минимум 2 раза:
1) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include
2) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Особенно посмотрите в сторону кастомных templatetags.

Answer (score 3):

есть понятие [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context). То есть ты пишешь функции, суть которых всегда возвращать тебе определенные словари в контекст.  Дальше все их в сеттингах определяешь.
Дальше когда ты уже непосредственно рендришь шаблон, указываешь дополнительный контекст который тебе нужен. Что-то в таком духе. Посмотри исходники для всяких app'ов типа User, Account, Flatpages.

```
return render_to_response('search/item_flats_print.html', { 
                              'object' : item,
                            'photo_items' : photo_items,
                            'tips':tips,
                                },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: спасибо учту.